# How to Add text to Hex Grid

Tags: jquery, text, grid, hex, position

I use this https://github.com/gojko/hexgridwidget
i want add text to position when user clicked.

```
<script>
<!-- main initialisation -->
var rebuild = function () {
  var
    radius = parseInt($('#radius').val()), 
    columns = parseInt($('#columns').val()), 
    rows = parseInt($('#rows').val()), 
    cssClass = 'hexfield';

  $('#container').empty().hexGridWidget(radius, columns, rows, cssClass).on('hexclick', function (e) { 
     $('#logger').text('clicked [' + e.column + ',' + e.row + '] hex with center at [' + e.center.x + ',' + e.center.y + '] px');
  });
  $('#container .hexfield').click(function () {
    this.classList.toggle('clicked');



    
    
  });
};
$('#rebuild').click(rebuild);
rebuild();
</script>
```

any help?